# Undefined variable: tab

Tags: php, yii2

Создал и перенес магазин на хостинг и в админ панели стала выскакивать ошибка при добавлении товара, подскажите пожалуйста как добавить эту переменную и куда.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

контроллер

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Product();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', "Товар {$model->name} добавлен");
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего данная переменная не передана через контроллер в вид.
Нужно инициализировать ее в контроллере и передать в представление методом **render()**

Comment: а все понял куда

Comment: вот эта часть, сейчас добавлю

Comment: как ее инициализировать ?

Comment: подскажи пожалуйста как передать ее, а то у меня ошибка за ошибкой передается, в рендере я ее добавил

Comment: Я не знаю что такое $tab в Вашем случае. 
Нужно получить эту переменную в контроллере - и передать в вид. 
Просто написать в render('tab') - не сработает.

Comment: tab это дефис в выпадающем списке категории, чтобы проставлялся - по уровню вложенности

Answer (score -1):

Отключите нотисы (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: Вот здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759041/disable-notice-yii более подробнее об этом